# OpenCSV reads strange text out of file

Tags: java, android, csv, file-handling, opencsv

I am using AndroidStudio and my applications has to read in a CSV file which looks like this:

```
"Anmeldung";"1576017126809898";"1547126680978123";"";"";"Frau"
"Anmeldung";"1547126680911112";"1547126680978123";"";"";"Frau"
```

But as you can see in the following picture, OpenCSV reads some strange character and in my List there are senseless Strings which are not in the file it read

[image: strange data]

This is how I read the Data out of my file:

```
        try {
        FileReader filereader = new FileReader(filePath);
        CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';').build();

        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(filereader)
                .withSkipLines(1)
                .withCSVParser(parser)
                .build();
        List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();
        MainActivity.setAllData(allData);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It might sound strange but I took the file and replaced all ; with ;
I think the data I got were exportet with an UTF-16 Encoding or from an linux device.

tl;dr The File had the wrong encoding. And the way I opened and viewed it was correct

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an encoding poblem.

Make sure to open and parse the file with the proper encoding (for example utf-8 or utf-16). Same for viewing the data.

Comment: I've double checked all encodings (editor and reader) everything is configurated with utf-8. It really seems like the csvreader reads my file wrong

Comment: @peldaftw I meant 'for example' utf-8 (or whatever the encoding the file is in).